# didReceiveRemoteNotification is not getting called after some time when the app is launched in the background by apns push

Tags: ios, react-native

It is called when app is in foreground and background and if it was launched in
background by apns push. but after some time it is not getting called if the app was
launched in background by apns .

```
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a whole lot of variables involved in mobile push delivery.

One of the main ones is that Apple states that only one message will be queued, the rest are discarded.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns

> APNs stores only one notification per bundle ID. When you send
> multiple notifications to the same device for a bundle ID, APNs
> selects only one notification to store in a non-deterministic way.

This page says 2 or 3 background notifications an hour: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

> The number of background notifications allowed by the system depends
> on current conditions, but don’t try to send more than two or three
> per hour.

"depends on current conditions" is a pretty magic phrase.

Current conditions appears to include:

- is the phone on charger
- if on battery is it on low charge
- does the device have wifi / 3G / no data
- has the phone been being used recently, or has it been sitting idle for a while
- has your app been being used recently, or left in the background for ages
- Does the user interact with your notifications, if you create them.
- how busy are the Apple servers
- Has your app been "force closed"
- How many other notifications are going to this device
- how many other notifications are you sending
- is it a rainy Tuesday in Cupertino ?

The last one ... not so sure of.

But I think the takeaway point is: APNS isn't a guaranteed delivery.  But it is a low battery usage way of getting a message to your app.